# I-Button jQuery Check Box

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm attempting to use the following jQuery code for check boxes for my website.

[I-Button Example](http://www.givainc.com/labs/ibutton_example.htm)

[I-Button jQuery Plugin](http://www.givainc.com/labs/ibutton_jquery_plugin.htm#options)

I have 2 javascript files, one which comes with the plug-in above and another .js file which performs calculations for site estimating.

I have a function within my site estimating file which calls the #selector of the checkbox

The Html:

```
<h6 class="R_C-first R_C">Image Gallery 
<input id="R_C-imgGalleryPrice" readonly="readonly" class="R_C" type="text" />
</h6>

<div class="row">
<label class="label" for="ex01">Default Off</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="R_C-imgGallery" name="imgGallery"/>
</div>
<input id="R_C-imgGalleryPrice2" readonly="readonly" class="R_C-floatRight R_C-width60 R_C" type="text" />
```

The Function:

```
       $R_C_imgGalleryPrice.val("(" + currency + imgGalleryPrice + ")");
    $R_C_imgGalleryPrice2.val(currency + 0);


   $R_C_imgGallery.click(function () {
        if ($R_C_imgGallery.is(':checked')) {
            $R_C_imgGalleryPrice2.val(currency + imgGalleryPrice);
            var total = parseInt($widgetsPrice.val());
            $widgetsPrice.val(total + imgGalleryPrice);
            $("#R_C-imgGalleryPrice2, #R_C-imgGalleryPrice, #R_C-imgGalleryAdded").addClass('R_C-added');
            $("#imgGalleryHidden").val('Yes');
            }

        else  
            {$R_C_imgGalleryPrice2.val(currency + 0);
            var total = parseInt($widgetsPrice.val());
            $widgetsPrice.val(total - imgGalleryPrice);
            $("#R_C-imgGalleryPrice2, #R_C-imgGalleryPrice, #R_C-imgGalleryAdded").removeClass('R_C-added');
            $("#imgGalleryHidden").val('No');
            }

    });
```

Here's where the Problem starts....When I add the I-Button .js file the code above will not execute any longer. No obvious errors are thrown in the browser.

As for the I-Button checkbox they are functioning just fine...

As for the check boxes they are all within a form tag and many different check boxes.

I dont know enough about jQuery yet to understand the problem fully. It seem like I need to Bind/pass the 2 function together somehow. I-Button instructs users to run the options through its function but its rather confusing to me at the moment.

One thing is obvious the I-Button function has taken priority over the estimation.js file.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar issue of my html dropdown elements not working with I-button js file included in page along with jquery file version 1.7.x. Changing the jquery file to latest version solves the dropdown issue but it hampers the I-button plugin.
So, try removing **false** from **return false** inside the plugin code and see if it works :

```
(document).bind("mousemove.iButton_"+T+" touchmove.iButton_"+T,function(c){if(O.clicked!=G){return false}c.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are adding this I-Button .js file its conflucting with you existing any jQuery file because some function are both in them so you remove one.

Comment: check the issue in mozilla ErrorConsole there should be give error jQuery undefined